# Is there a better approach to minify html generated from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following code to minify html generated from aspx page duuring runtime.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    TextWriter output = new StringWriter();
    base.Render(new HtmlTextWriter(output));
    String html = output.ToString();
    html = Regex.Replace(html, @"\n|\t", " ");
    html = Regex.Replace(html, @">\s+<", "><").Trim();
    html = Regex.Replace(html, @"\s{2,}", " ");

    writer.Write(html);
}
```

Is there more better approach to do the same.

Thank you so much.

Comment: unless you have a very string reason, I wouldn't recommend HTML minify. You save bandwidth but the generated HTML is unreadable. Be sure that you optimized everything else before taking this step :-)

Comment: IIS 7 (server 2008) also has a setting to do response compression (gzip).  The default is to use compression for all static content but not for dynamic content.  Turning it on for dynamic content will eat up more CPU but it compresses output from ASPX pretty nicely.

Comment: @Claudio Redi , do I need to read generated HTML? FireBug can beautify unreadable HTML. As the .aspx page minifies the output HTML, my original .aspx page remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by using [Html Tidy](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/article/20505/0/page/2) or even an [HTTP Module](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/httpcompression.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    using (HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter()))
    {
        base.Render(htmlwriter);
        string html = htmlwriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
        html = Regex.Replace(html, @"(?<=[^])\t{2,}|(?<=[>])\s{2,}(?=[<])|(?<=[>])\s{2,11}(?=[<])|(?=[\n])\s{2,}", "");
        html = Regex.Replace(html, @"[ \f\r\t\v]?([\n\xFE\xFF/{}[\];,<>*%&|^!~?:=])[\f\r\t\v]?", "$1");
        html = html.Replace(";\n", ";");
        writer.Write(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is better? and by the way, both your method and the OP method will delete needed space in a case like: `<a href="#">Links here</a> > <a href="#">Links2</a>` the result will be (visually): `Links here >Links2` instead of `Links here > Links2`